# To span the login button across two columns using CSS and HTML only

Tags: html, css

I want to span the login submit button in the above code in two columns and it is not working properly. I tried it many times but its still not working. can anyone provide a correct way to do this

```css
            form {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 10vw);
            }
    
            #submit {
                column-span: all;
            }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Assignment 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Login / Sign-In</h2>
        <form>
            <label for="uname">Username: <sup>*</sup> </label>
            <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname">
    
            <label for="passwd">Password: <sup>*</sup> </label>
            <input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd">
    
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `grid-column` property:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        form {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 10vw);
        }

        #submit {
            grid-column: 1 / span 2;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Assignment 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Login / Sign-In</h2>
    <form>
        <label for="uname">Username: <sup>*</sup> </label>
        <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname">

        <label for="passwd">Password: <sup>*</sup> </label>
        <input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd">

        <button type="submit" id="submit" >Login</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 10vw);`, you can achieve with your CSS if you use `column-count: 2;`

```css
            form {
                display: grid;
                column-count: 2;
                width: 30%;
            }
    
            button {
                column-span: all;
                margin-top: 5px;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Assignment 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Login / Sign-In</h2>
        <form>
            <label for="uname">Username: <sup>*</sup> </label>
            <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname">
    
            <label for="passwd">Password: <sup>*</sup> </label>
            <input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd">
    
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I want to span only the submit button whereas you're suggestion is giving this 
[Output](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/76511000/125799339-5638b871-7e60-406c-9bd3-3141bd649a53.png)